# Why emulators launched with NativeScript project (with Angular) don't work as aspected?

Tags: android-emulator, emulation, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've just start a default project following the guide on NativeScript website ( http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1 )
My problem is that when I try to run android emulator, after a while (about 1 min) it turns to a black screen, whereas the ios one doesn't work at all raising an error that says:

> Unable to apply changes on device:
>   7C7B68A2-2FFA-4940-8E46-4C6BC644EFDB. Error is: Command failed: ruby
>   -e "require 'xcodeproj'; Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/fulvioantoniocoscobarletta/FulDev/NativeScript/goHenryApp/goHenry/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig').merge(Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/fulvioantoniocoscobarletta/FulDev/NativeScript/goHenryApp/goHenry/app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig')).save_as(Pathname.new('/Users/fulvioantoniocoscobarletta/FulDev/NativeScript/goHenryApp/goHenry/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig'))"
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from -e:1:in `'

I'm using

```
NodeJs 6.11.1 
Npm 3.10.10 
NativeScript 3.1.3 
Angular 4.1
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm awful with environment setup stuff :( so I'm not great help but you might want to update npm to 4+. As for this issue it definitely seems like an environment issue on your machine. My setup works as does most people I'd say and setup is just the worst :). Sorry for not being super helpful. You might find some good help on the NS slack community about this issue or the forum site.

Comment: The android emulator that is fired up may not be optimized, hence the black screen, not nativescript-specific error.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently hit this after an upgrade for High Sierra. I had to reinstall `xcodeproj`: sudo gem install xcodeproj. Seems to have done the trick.